# Does a grass path block spread grass to adjacent dirt blocks?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When a grass block is turned into a [grass path](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Grass_Path) block with a shovel, does it continue to propagate grass to adjacent dirt blocks, or is the grass then "dead"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have run an experiment and grass path does not spread grass to dirt.
[image: Image here.]

Setting the random tick speed to 1,000 meant that things like wheat growing or grass spreading in this case are a lot faster with the default being 3. I suspect this is because the two blocks are stored differently. Grass is minecraft:grass whereas path is minecraft:grass_path.

Answer (score 1):

No. Grass paths will not spread grass, which means you can keep the area barren if you want to.